# PHP $_GET superglobal curiosity

Tags: php, get

student here,

just learned about $_GET superglobal and how the programmer has to physically input keys and values in the URL
(i.e [www.randomStuff.com/otherStuff.php](http://www.randomStuff.com/otherStuff.php) **?x=1&y=2** ) and that the $_GET method 'grabs' this information and stores it in an array..

out of curiosity i wanted to ask professional programmers,
in what cases do you do so?

when and why do you need to insert variables in the url and then use $_GET?

apologies in advance if this seams like a stupid question but i was curious about this

cheers for taking time in elucidating me on the matter

Comment: Say a common file download link for all files on your web app. It's nice to send a file name in GET parameter for the server to know which file to send for download. There are a lot of other scenarios though. $_GET is used usually(or actually should be) for insensitive data.

Comment: You would do that whenever you need your script to be interactive, ie. respond to user input (which is typically most of the time). *Query string* is one of the most common and fundamental aspects of creating interactive websites/applications in any language.

Comment: Imagine the homepage of a blog that lists a bunch of posts. To read one specific post, the url can be like: `post.php?id=123` (where 123 is the post id). When the link is clicked, it will go to `post.php`, you grab the id using `$id = $_GET['id']` and can now load and view the correct post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that you are creating a web site which shows a list of products, and want to link to a details page for each of those products.

Your list would generate URLs like `https://example.com/productDetail?productId=159`